# How do I explain Identifer Expected

Tags: java

Good Day,

I have a question on theory

```
public class ExamQ1a {    
    double a, b, c, s, area;
    a = 3;
    b = 4;
    c = 5;
    area = Math.sqrt(s (s-a) (s-b) (s-c));
    s = (a + b + c) / 2;
    System.out.println("area = " + area); 
}
```

I have a question based on past exam paper; During compilation, statement [a = 3;] is highlighted and an error message (identifier expected) is shown.  Explain what the problem is and how to fix it?

I know that it should be inside a method but how do i properly explain it?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the link with theory? Isn't that Java? I guess that you should write `s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that the class definition is evaluated at compile-time, so initializers like `double a = 3;` are permitted by some compilers, but statements like `a = 3;` that are not contained within a method or constructor would never be executed, and so are not permitted.